# Select count takes two minutes on a two column table

Tags: mysql, mariadb

I have a MariaDB table with just under 100000 rows, and selecting the count takes a very long time (almost 2 minutes).

Selecting anything by id from the table though takes only 4 milliseconds.

The text field here contains on average 5000 characters.

How can I speed this up?

```
MariaDB [companies]> describe company_details;
+---------+------------------+------+-----+---------+-------+
| Field   | Type             | Null | Key | Default | Extra |
+---------+------------------+------+-----+---------+-------+
| id      | int(10) unsigned | NO   | PRI | NULL    |       |
| details | text             | YES  |     | NULL    |       |
+---------+------------------+------+-----+---------+-------+

MariaDB [companies]> explain select count(id) from company_details;
+------+-------------+-----------------+-------+---------------+---------+---------+------+-------+-------------+
| id   | select_type | table           | type  | possible_keys | key     | key_len | ref  | rows  | Extra       |
+------+-------------+-----------------+-------+---------------+---------+---------+------+-------+-------------+
|    1 | SIMPLE      | company_details | index | NULL          | PRIMARY | 4       | NULL | 71267 | Using index |
+------+-------------+-----------------+-------+---------------+---------+---------+------+-------+-------------+

MariaDB [companies]> analyze table company_details;
+---------------------------+---------+----------+----------+
| Table                     | Op      | Msg_type | Msg_text |
+---------------------------+---------+----------+----------+
| companies.company_details | analyze | status   | OK       |
+---------------------------+---------+----------+----------+
1 row in set (0.098 sec)

MariaDB [companies]> select count(id) from company_details;
+-----------+
| count(id) |
+-----------+
|     96544 |
+-----------+
1 row in set (1 min 43.199 sec)
```

This becomes an even bigger problem when I try to join the table.
For example, to find the number of companies which do not have associated details:

```
MariaDB [companies]> SELECT COUNT(*) FROM company c LEFT JOIN company_details cd ON c.id = cd.id WHERE cd.id IS NULL;
+----------+
| count(*) |
+----------+
|    42178 |
+----------+
1 row in set (10 min 28.846 sec)
```

Edit:
After running OPTIMIZE on the table, the select count has improved speed from 1min 43sec to just 5 sec, and the join has improved speed from 10 minutes to 25 seconds.

```
MariaDB [companies]> optimize table company_details;
+---------------------------+----------+----------+-------------------------------------------------------------------+
| Table                     | Op       | Msg_type | Msg_text                                                          |
+---------------------------+----------+----------+-------------------------------------------------------------------+
| companies.company_details | optimize | note     | Table does not support optimize, doing recreate + analyze instead |
| companies.company_details | optimize | status   | OK                                                                |
+---------------------------+----------+----------+-------------------------------------------------------------------+
2 rows in set (11 min 21.195 sec)
```

Comment: Rebuild the index on the ID. Even if u have it by default because the ID is the primary key that doesn't mean the index is optimized. Use ANALYZE TABLE to check this table.

Comment: What is the value of `innodb_buffer_pool_size`?  `SHOW TABLE STATUS LIKE company%;`  (Those may give me some clues toward answering your question.)

Comment: Also, is there some reason to keep the two tables separate?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think there's OPTIMIZE -command for rebuilding indexes.

```
OPTIMIZE TABLE company_details;
```

This usually takes some time to complete. More details: https://mariadb.com/kb/en/optimize-table/